# Image filter to separate ricegrains

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to solve an image filtering issue with [MATLAB 2013a](http://in.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/sv-r2013a/). Here are two images on which I am trying to work.
[image: Successfully done]
[image: Looking impossible to filter]

My aim is to obtain each rice grain as a separate image.

Following is the process I used and was successful for the first image.

1. Convert to gray scale,
2. Obtain grey threshold,
3. Convert to binary,
4. Perform dilation and erosion for more accurate filtering,
5. Use connected component analysis with [bwconncomp](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html),
6. Save each component.

Now if I try to achieve similar binary image for image2, all the rice grain connected to each other comes as a single component.

I have tried to derive [edge](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) map with 'canny' or any other like 'sobel', its not working.

Can someone please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: It seems intrinsically harder to separate the grains in the second picture since so many of them are touching. Dilating first will certainly not help. A sequence of erosion -> dilation -> erosion often helps me, but it's necessary to fine-tune the arguments at each step.

Comment: I can't see the images on this PC (silly company security policy :-P), but this kind of problem is sometimes tackled using watershedding. See the [`watershed`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html) function and [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html).

Comment: @Naveh I tried that also. No luck! The rice grains are too close. Also tried for detectSURFFeatures, extractFeatures and matchFeatures so that few might get detected, but there also no luck.

Comment: You might need to use more of the information in your image. For instance, you are often getting very dark lines between two closely spaced grains owing to the shadows. The grains themselves are quite bright (though darker than the background). So instead of the standard binary conversion, you could convert to binary using two thresholds: if the grayscale pixel is not too light and also not too dark, it's set to 1 in the binary. This could reduce the apparent overlap between grains.

Comment: I would use edge detection in addition to color. Also, use the shape of the grain in the recognition, and handle shared edges. Another possibility is to use two or three images of the same set of rice, each with different light angles to show well-defined shadows.

Comment: Tried edge detection, the amount of edges present in each grain and their proximity makes it almost impossible, even for human eye, to make out the boundaries. Shape recognition is good idea, but i am unclear on how to implement it. A little more elaboration would be great help.

Comment: These rice grains look predominantly like ellipses.  Try using a randomized Hough Transform specifically tailored for ellipse fitting.  This way, you will detect individual ellipses (i.e. the rice grains). A good MATLAB implementation is posted on MATLAB FEX here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33970-ellipse-detection-using-1d-hough-transform

Comment: Can you try this. Break the image into smaller sub images. Resize the smaller image to a larger image and then apply the previous analysis.

Comment: Can you add images to show us what you get at each of your 6 steps please? Maybe then someone will be able to improve one or two steps and someone else improve a couple of other steps and we may get there piecemeal rather than one person having to solve the entire problem. Just a thought!

Comment: http://www.ias-iss.org/ojs/IAS/article/viewFile/862/765